# How to open a webpage with the built-in (stock) android browser?

Tags: android

There are multiple browsers installed. How can I open http://www.google.com programatically with the built-in (stock) browser?

Answer (score 2):

Using the built-in browser, you can usually make the address bar appear by pressing the menu button (after opening the browser by pressing the icon of course).  Once that is open, you can enter the google URL you specified using the keyboard (hardware or software version depending on which handset you have.)

Comment: In that case ask on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

This code forms an intent with url in data section. Then it starts an application binded to ACTION_VIEW according the uri.(a browser in case of http). Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW).

```
String url = "http://google.com/";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code  will open the page in the users preferred browser. Source [Tutorial for Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20200210093614/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/04/open-urlwebsite-from-android.html)

```
String url = "http://almondmendoza.com/android-applications/";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Is there any particular reason you specifically want the default browser?

Don't forget some handsets, like HTCs, don't come with the default browser as standard

Comment: Can I ask why you down voted me for this answer? I answered your question with a decent base answer, a question that would help inform people about the question and a worthy point to note. A downvote seems a little harsh on someone who was just trying to help.

Comment: His question clearly states, that on a system with multiple browsers installed, he wants to open the STOCK android browser, and not the users preferred browser.

Comment: sorry but this question is months old. Leave it to die. Also he shouldn't want to open the stock browser as the point of intents is to let the user decide what app to use for each intent. Forcing one browser is too apple like for Android